# IntelliJ 12 Android Setup? Nothing works

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-manifest

IntelliJ 12 does not generate the needed files to start Android Development.
I've setup both JDK and SDK and intelliJ seems to see the correct paths.

I am coming from Eclipse which generates everything you need to start pretty much out of the box.

I've tried...

- Double triple checking file paths.
- Searching...alot of searching.
  Making new files from scratch.
- Making hello world program, still doesn't generate needed res folder and AndroidManifest.xml file.
- Changing file path directly to AndroidManifest.xml's containing folder.

Comment: Check if android support is enabled in Idea. `Settings` -> `Plugins` -> Check `Android support` checkbox.

Comment: Please contact support@jetbrains.com with `idea.log` if it still doesn't work: `Help` | `Reveal Log in ...`

Answer (score 1):

The one thing Eclipse provides that is missing from IntelliJ is and Android SDK install wizard. In other words, you would have to preinstall hte Android SDK from Google prior to starting with IntelliJ. Other than that IntelliJ actually provides more out of the box than Eclipse. (Especially considering you have to manually install the Android plugin before you get the Android SDK install wizard.) Go to the Google Android developer site to find the Android SDK and once you've done that you should be able to get up and running pretty quickly with IntelliJ. Start a new project and select Android. This should walk you through a new project wizard which will setup the necessary res and gen folders for you.

I've put together a screencast on Android development using an Eclipse stub project here: http://bit.ly/Zu6q8i